# How to render 3 column Kendo HTML template for Kendo Details Grid?

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

How can i render a detail template like this screenshot? i want to render a details inner grid that displays the assignments in sections in 3 columns as pictured. The code that I have right now just renders them all in one long column and not split into three sections.Below I provided code that is the parent grid and the detailinit section for inner grid. is there anyway to make a KendoList view inside the grid?
The DetailsInit takes in data from a Handler and send Ids to complete that function.

[image]

This is my code so far

```
    export function configureSearchGrid() {
    $("#parentgrid").kendoGrid({
        autoBind: true,
        dataSource: data,
        scrollable: false,
        sortable: false,
        filterable: {
            mode: "row"
        },
        pageable: {
            refresh: false,
            pageSize: 10,
            pageSizes: [15, 30, 50],
            buttonCount: 4
        },
        noRecords: { "template": "\u003cdiv class=\u0027grid-norecords\u0027\u003eNo Records were found.\u003c/div\u003e" },
        detailInit: detailInit,
        columns: [
            { field: "ShiftId", title: "Shift", width: "55px", filterable: false, attributes: { style: 'text-align: center' }},
        ],
    });
}
  function detailInit(e) {
    $("<div/>").appendTo(e.detailCell).kendoGrid({
        autoBind: true,
        resizable: false,
        scrollable: false,
        columns: [
            { field: "Assignment", title: "Shift Assignment", width: "150px"}, //TODO NEED TO CREATE CUSTOM TEMPLATE 
        ],
        noRecords: {
            template: "<div class='grid-norecords'>No records were found.</div>"
        },
        dataSource: {
            transport: {
                read: {
                    url: "?handler=LoadAssignment",
                    data: function () {
                        return { shiftId: e.data.ShiftId, establishmentId: e.data.EstablishmentId };
                    }
                }
            },
            schema: {
                data: "Data",
                total: "Total",
            },
            data: function (data) {
                return data.Data
            },
            total: function (data) {
                return data.Total
            },
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a ListView in the detail template. Instead of a Grid initialize a ListView. You'll also need a template to render the ListView items, as desired, and add some CSS, so the ListView container renders the items in 3 columns. Here is a [modified Kendo UI example](https://dojo.telerik.com/ESawisoX) demonstrating just that:

```
   function detailInit(e) {
      var detailRow = e.detailRow;

      detailRow.find(".orders").kendoListView({
        dataSource: {
          type: "odata",
          transport: {
            read: "https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/service/Northwind.svc/Orders"
          },
          serverPaging: true,
          serverSorting: true,
          serverFiltering: true,
          pageSize: 21,
          filter: { field: "EmployeeID", operator: "eq", value: e.data.EmployeeID }
        },
        template: kendo.template($("#listviewTemplate").html()),
        pageable: true
      });
    }
  
  
  <script type="text/x-kendo-template" id="listviewTemplate">
    <div class="product">
        <h3>#=OrderID#</h3>
        <p>#=ShipName#</p>
    </div>
  </script>
  
  <style>
    .k-listview-content{
      display:grid;
      grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    }
  </style>
```